# Connecting Health Bar to Damage dealt

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and together with a few friends, I try to make a game. I was trying to connect the healthbar I made to the damage u can deal by shooting knifes. First to test this I used:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            TakeDamage(25);
        }
      
    }
```

Everything worked fine and when I pressed Mouse1 the healthbar worked.My goal was, that when a knife hits the enemy 25 damage is dealt and the healthbar shows that the enemy lost health. However, when the knifes hit the enemy nothing happens. Can you please help me because I tried fixing this for like 3 hours and I'm getting kinda frustrated. Thank you.

Here's the code for the healthbar:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class healthbar : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider slider;

    public void SetMaxHealth(int health)
    {
        slider.maxValue = health;
        slider.value = health;
    }
    
    public void SetHealth(int health)
    {
        slider.value = health;
    }
}
```

And here's the code for the enemy:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy_Follow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform target;
    public int damage = 25;
    public int maxHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth;
    public healthbar healthBar;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
        target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Transform>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            TakeDamage(25);
        }
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Knife")
        {
            TakeDamage(25);
        }
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;
        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that a) `OnTriggerEnter2D` is called at all? Do your objects have `Collider2D`? Is one of the colliders a `isTrigger`? Do you have `Rigidbody2D` on at least one if them? b) the Tag is correct? Rather use `CompareTag` instead of `==` in general to avoid silent fails for typos. c) are you getting any errors in the console? Besides these I don't see why this shouldn't work

Comment: Ah, did you attach collider component to your enemy and knife? Unless you attached collision collider to your component, OnTriggerEnter2D doesn't work.

Comment: There are just a view possible reasons why it may not work. 1. Wrong Tag. 2. No Collider 3. Collider not set as trigger. I guess its the last and u may switch to `OnCollisionEnter2D`

Comment: So both objects have RigidBody 2D and Collider 2D. I also checked the tag and it's correct. I also changed == to Compare Tag and I don't get any errors. However none of the colliders have an isTrigger and I guess thats the problem. Is there an alternative for OnTriggerEnter2D? Because if I change one of the colliders to isTrigger the knifes either fly through the enemy or the enemy can walk through walls and can't get hit by the knifes.

Comment: After switching to OnCollisionEnter2D I get the following error: Script error: OnCollisionEnter2D
This message parameter has to be of type: Collision2D
The message will be ignored. My Code now looks like this                               public void                                                                     OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag ("Knife"))
        {
            TakeDamage(25);
        }
    }

Comment: @hunnedsd you get this error because you use Collider2D instead of Collision2D. Your Code should look like this `void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) { // TODO }`

Comment: Just so u understand the difference between OnCollision and OnTrigger. Every Collider in Unity has a bool where you can set isTrigger = true. An Collider in Unity makes that 2 objects can interect with each other with Physics. If you set the Trigger your collider wont work for collisions anymore but just for OnTrigger. So you like still have the same possibilitys by code but it doesnt interact with other colliders in a physical way anymore.

Comment: @hunnedsd when your question is answered you may check one of the answeres so it shows up as solved/answered.

Answer (score 0):

After finding out that your colliders are **not** triggers it should rather be [`OnCollisionEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) like e.g.

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Knife"))
    {
        TakeDamage(25);
    }
}
```

See also [Colliders -> Collision Action Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Answer (score -1):

You may try this code to look if the slider works at all. If this code does work (You can change things with the inspector) then it should be an error with the collision/trigger detection and nothing else.

```cs
public class SliderTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public Slider slider;
    public int maxHealth = 100;
    private int currentHealth = 100;

    public bool resetHealth = false;
    public bool damage = false;

    void Start() {
        slider = GetComponent<Slider>();
        SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }
    
    void Update() {
        if(resetHealth) {
            resetHealth = false;
            SetHealth(maxHealth);
        }
        if(damage) {
            damage = false;
            SetHealth(currentHealth-10);
        }
    }

    public void SetMaxHealth(int health) {
        slider.maxValue = health;
        slider.value = 100;
    }

    public void SetHealth(int health) {
        currentHealth = health;
        slider.value = currentHealth;
    }
}
}
```